# Aws lambda with mongoDb connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda, api-gateway

Hello guyz i need an answer to an simple question.I am using Aws lambda with serverless framework and i am using mongoDb connection in aws lambda.I have used connection code inside my handler function and i have used connection pooling.

Now when i deploy my app on AWS using sls deploy and after deploying when i call my lambda for first time then connection is established only once and after that on other lambda API calls it is reusing my connection instead of creating new connection.so this thing is fine.

Now after this process i am running a script which is not related with my AWS app to test my concurrent lambda requests.I have called my same lambda API using request npm module in for loop in script and in that case all time my new connnection is created till loop terminates instead of using my existing one generated from first call.Can someone tell me why it is happening and what is the reason behind this? Why my connection is creating again when  this script runs when already i have created my connection on first lambda call.

And same api when i call from postman then it is resuing my connection after first lambda call but when i run this script and from inside script i call this API(using request NPM module) using command "node app.js"  then all time till loop terminates it creates new connection.

Please help me out in this.

```
 'use strict'

 const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
 const express = require('express')
 const serverless = require('serverless-http')
 const cors = require('cors');
 const mongoConnection = require('./connection/mongoDb');
 const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())

const handler = serverless(app);
let cachedDb = null;

module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
if (cachedDb == null) {
let Database = await mongoConnection();
console.log("DB", Database);
cachedDb = Database
}

const baseRouter = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/api', baseRouter);

const result = await handler(event, context);
return result;
};
```

Comment: Will you share any of your code snippets?

Comment: I have used normal code of aws lambda with mongodb connection from official site there is no issue in code.How the concept is working that i am not understanding.

Comment: @Ali From here i have used code https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/best-practices-connecting-to-aws-lambda/

Comment: Without the actual code that you deploy to lambda it is really hard to say anything about this, I can take a look if you post the handler code. But if I had to guess, it has to do with how you scope the connection variable and container re-use (see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/).

Comment: i have added code please look into this @LucHendriks

Comment: this is my aws lambda code and this code i am deploying to lambda and after that in a dummy script i am calling this API using request NPM module in for loop @LucHendriks

Comment: @AdityaSharma have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a node.js example that shows the connection parameters.  Perhaps this will help?

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser= require("body-parser")
const app = express();
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient


MongoClient.connect("mongodb://myusername:mypassword@localhost:27017", (err, client) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)

  var db = client.db("mydatabase")

  db.collection("mycollection").countDocuments(getCountCallback);

  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("listening on 3000")
  })  
})


function getCountCallback(err, data) {
  console.log(data);
}

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
})

app.post("/quotes", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
})
```

Your example code does not show any hostname for your database server, nor does it specify which port to use.  Please compare your code and contrast to my example.

Comment: I dont want code i want to know the concept of lambda container working in detail.Please read my question from start to end you will  come to know easily what i want to know

Comment: @AdityaSharma - You need to specify a connection string.  Without some coding you will not be able to integrate lambda functions with MongoDB.  I wish you the best!

Answer (score 0):

I see you defined the cachedDb variable outside the handler scope, so that makes it available when the container is reused. However, there is no guarantee that the container will be reused (see my previous link on that) because that's not how Lambda works. If you invoke the same functions many times very quickly after eachother, Lambda needs to scale out horizontally to be able to handle the requests quickly. They each get their own container and connection.

When the invocation is finished, AWS will keep the container for a bit (how long depends on many factors like function size & RAM limit). If you invoke it again the containers can reuse their connection. You can try to invoke the function 20 times with 1 second interval and counting the number of connections that have been openend. It will be lower than 20, but higher than 1.